# Invoking one application in the other

Tags: asp.net

I have one solution with web forms approach (soln1) and the other one in MVC 2.0 (soln2). On a page page1.aspx in soln1, I want to render soln2. I used iFrame and in src atribute, I provided starting URL of soln2. Is there any other approach to this? Basically I dont want to use iFrame because of some styling issues.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Rohit, how did you get along with my updated answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways (that I can think of) to load one webpage inside another:

- IFrame
- jquery.load
- Frames

Unfortunately all of these options have their problems.

IFrame's can have styling issues as you know.

JQuery's load has compatibility problems with some browsers and an issue with event bubbling.

Frames demands a static layout to your site and probably has the same styling issue for you.

Considering those problems, an IFrame is probably the best choice, it's also specifically intended for the kind of behaviour you're trying to achieve.

Why don't you post about your styling problems, as that might be the easier thing to solve.

Update:

To fix the scroll bars, you can add this attribute to your iframe

```
scrolling="no"
```

For an example see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/FZ4eZ/

Comment: Thanks Russ. My issue is specifically with the width of iFrame. When contents inside the frame overflows, iFrame shows the scrollbar and not the parent page (page1.aspx). Hene 2 borders are coming on a screen.

Comment: Just off the top of my head, can you set overflow:hidden on the IFrame's style or CSS class ?

Comment: No. It wont work. In short, what I want is, iFrame to work as <div> in the cases of overflowing internal content.

Comment: Updated my answer with a solution.